# Better and cheaper Raspberry Pi alternative for BOINC

Tags: power

As the title states, I am planning to make a cluster to donate its processing power to boinc. I am looking for a equally powerful or even more powerful board that costs less than the raspberry pi 2/3. I want it to be compatible with Gridcoin Wallet. I also want to run Raspbian/Debian on the boards.

To sum everything up,

1. A computer that's more/equivalant in terms of power with the RPi 2/3 but cheaper. Amazon UK links are appreciated, you can send me eBay UK links if there are any special offers. I want it to be new NOT USED.
2. The computer shouldn't have unnecessary features like built in wifi, if the board has it, then it's fine. The computer should be able to run Gridcoin Wallet and can be able to run on Debian/Raspbian

Hopefully that sums it all up...

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Many thanks!

Sid

Answer (score 1):

If you need that kind of performance at a lower price, you could try these:

- $20 Orange Pi PC 2: http://www.orangepi.org/orangepipc2/
- $19 Pine A64+ 1GB: https://www.pine64.org/?product=pine-a64-board-1gb

The Pine A64+ is quite a bit larger than the RPi though, I would say that it has roughly twice the surface area. Both boards have the added advantage of gigabit ethernet.